# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined in raphael.js

Tags: raphael

Was using `justgage`  [node_module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/justgage) in the below code. On importing raphael.js for the same, getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`. When I checked the method giving issue in the file, it was found that the method was already defined in the code. 
Code giving issue is  `eve.on("raphael.remove", stopAnimation);` on line `5216` in raphael.js but this method was already defined on line `185` as `eve.on = function (name, f){}`. Can anybody tell what is the problem ?

Code -

```
import React from 'react';
import 'justgage';
import 'raphael';

var timeOut=null,gauge=null;

export default React.createClass({

        componentDidMount(){            
            this.update();                  
        },

        update(){

            gauge=new JustGage({ id: "gauge", value: 67, min: 0, max: 100, title: "Visitors"});
            document.getElementById("gage").innerHTML = gauge;      

            timeOut=setTimeout(this.update, 600);       
        },

        getValue(){
         var val = 25*Math.random();
            if(val>100) { val=100-val;}
            if(val<0)   { val=val+10;}
          return val;
        },

      componentWillUnmount: function() {        
         clearTimeout(timeOut);
      },

       render(){
                return(<div className="coll-md-4">
                         <div id="gage"></div>  
                       </div>);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-raphael package.

ps. if you haven't jQuery available globally, you can pass using [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader) module:

```
import 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery,this=>window!webpack-raphael/raphael';
```